# TypeScript Mongoose method does not exists on type <Context = any>

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

How to create a schema method that compare passwords using Mongoose & TypeScript?

```
interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
  comparePassword(
    candidatePassword: string,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Promise<boolean>;
}

userSchema.method.comparePassword = async function (
  this: IUser,
  canditatePassword: string,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  try {
    let isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(canditatePassword, this.password);
    return isMatch;
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

I want to create a schema method using TypeScript and I've got a type error for the "comparePassword" method:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different interfaces for:

- properties
- instance methods

then create a new type like so

```
// Create a new Model type that knows about IUserMethods...
type UserModel = Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods>;
```

you could find an example at the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics-and-methods.html)